# Building customized opencv android library

Tags: android, opencv

I'm following this link to make customized opencv library to reduce the size of it. But as Andrey Kamaev suggested i'm trying to exclude unnecessary modules but i can't find these statements

```
SET(OPENCV_JAVA_MODULES objdetect features2d imgproc video highgui ml core calib3d)
SET(OPENCV_EXTRA_JAVA_MODULES contrib legacy flann)
```

in my CMakeLists.txt file at modules/java folder. I'm using opencv 2.4 version. Please can you guide me or anyone know proper tutorial/ documentation for this purpos.